# android how to program a stopwatch with SharedPreference

Tags: java, android

I'm programming a stopwatch in android sdk but I want to keep going even when I press back. I understand the activity lifecycle to some extent and I should overrive the onPause and onResume methods but have no idea how to go with that since SharePreference editor can't take in a Chronometer object

```
    package com.example.taekwondobuddy.util;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;



 public class Time extends Activity {
 Chronometer mChronometer;

@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

mChronometer = new Chronometer(this);
layout.addView(mChronometer);

Button startButton = new Button(this);
startButton.setText("Start");
startButton.setOnClickListener(mStartListener);
layout.addView(startButton);

Button stopButton = new Button(this);
stopButton.setText("Stop");
stopButton.setOnClickListener(mStopListener);
layout.addView(stopButton);

Button resetButton = new Button(this);
resetButton.setText("Reset");
resetButton.setOnClickListener(mResetListener);
layout.addView(resetButton);        

setContentView(layout);
}



View.OnClickListener mStartListener = new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    mChronometer.start();

}
};

View.OnClickListener mStopListener = new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    mChronometer.stop();

}
};

View.OnClickListener mResetListener = new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

 }
 };
 }
```

any tips or advice? Help is appreciated!

Comment: You want to pause chronometer and save state when back pressed?

Comment: yes, I want it state to be where I left it off when I go back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// try this
public class Time extends Activity {
    Chronometer mChronometer;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.app_name), MODE_PRIVATE);
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        mChronometer = new Chronometer(this);

        layout.addView(mChronometer);

        Button startButton = new Button(this);
        startButton.setText("Start");
        startButton.setOnClickListener(mStartListener);
        layout.addView(startButton);

        Button stopButton = new Button(this);
        stopButton.setText("Stop");
        stopButton.setOnClickListener(mStopListener);
        layout.addView(stopButton);

        Button resetButton = new Button(this);
        resetButton.setText("Reset");
        resetButton.setOnClickListener(mResetListener);
        layout.addView(resetButton);

        setContentView(layout);
    }

    private void showElapsedTime() {
        long elapsedMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mChronometer.getBase();
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Elapsed milliseconds: " + elapsedMillis,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    View.OnClickListener mStartListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int stoppedMilliseconds = 0;

            String chronoText = mChronometer.getText().toString();
            String array[] = chronoText.split(":");
            if (array.length == 2) {
                stoppedMilliseconds = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) * 60 * 1000
                        + Integer.parseInt(array[1]) * 1000;
            } else if (array.length == 3) {
                stoppedMilliseconds = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) * 60 * 60 * 1000
                        + Integer.parseInt(array[1]) * 60 * 1000
                        + Integer.parseInt(array[2]) * 1000;
            }

            mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - stoppedMilliseconds);
            mChronometer.start();
        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener mStopListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mChronometer.stop();
        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener mResetListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        prepareSharedData();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mChronometer.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("time", "00:00"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        prepareSharedData();
    }

    public void prepareSharedData(){
        String chronoText = mChronometer.getText().toString();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("time", chronoText);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue your countdown where you left it off than you need shared preferences other wise if you want to keep going stop watch even when user press back button you don't need Shared-Preference, shared-preference used to store primitive and string data types, You can use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) to perform this operation,Still if you are using Chronometer you can not store [Chronometer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html) itself in shared preferences instead its values returned by `elapsedRealtime()` or from other methods of [Chronometer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html)
In AsyncTask or Service you can keep polling `elapsedRealtime()` , `AsyncTask` keep alive untill its `doInBackground` method finishes,even if you press back button `AsyncTask` keep alive